# Google Auth in expo 49

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth

I'm following a tutorial from 2 months ago for how to use google-auth, on my expo app.
there were a few outdated things, related to Expo-CLI changes, but i managed to learn how to use ESA-CLI for that.

Everything works when i run web, the whole authentication flow.
When i try Android or iOS, i get the same error in both, after trying to authenticate:

```
Error 400: url_redirect_mismatch
```

I landed on this question / answer:
[expo-auth-google to expo-auth-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75763469/expo-auth-google-to-expo-auth-session)
and followed the instructions on the answer,

```
import { makeRedirectUri } from 'expo-auth-session'
...

const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    ...googleConfig,
    redirectUri: makeRedirectUri(),
  })
```

and i got a different error:

```
Error 400: invalid_request
Request details: redirect_uri=expo-google-auth://
```

I have no idea how to fix it and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working for me

```js
import { makeRedirectUri } from 'expo-auth-session';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';

const EXPO_REDIRECT_PARAMS = {
  useProxy: true,
  projectNameForProxy: '@yourUsername/yourScheme',
};

const NATIVE_REDIRECT_PARAMS = { native: 'yourScheme://' };

const REDIRECT_PARAMS =
  Constants.appOwnership === 'expo'
    ? EXPO_REDIRECT_PARAMS
    : NATIVE_REDIRECT_PARAMS;

const GOOGLE_CONFIG = {
  androidClientId: '...',
  webClientId: '...',
  iosClientId: '...',
  redirectUri: makeRedirectUri(REDIRECT_PARAMS),
};

const LoginPage = ()=> {
     const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest(GOOGLE_CONFIG)
     ...

}
```